# Update Panel using async method for live information to a label or other

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, updatepanel

I am writing a web application and occasionally a process runs for a few seconds. When this is the case I need to update the page to show the process is still running. i.e. a database call etc however I cant seem to get a control to update multiple times. For example a label to update each second i.e. Stage 1, Stage 2 etc. (purely for testing the read code is a stored procedure which returns a result)

I have wrapped the controls inside the usual Update Panel with a script manager on the page, I have tried linking the button control as a trigger to the update panel however I can only ever show the final result. for example I will set a label.text = "case 1" and in the same method for testing delay for 1 second and then update the label again. This works in desktop c# environments such as WPF etc but not in ASP.NET with an aspx page and code behind.

```
    protected async void btnTakeTime_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Button press we await each call which in turn lets the label
        await TimeTaker(1);
        await TimeTaker(2);
        await TimeTaker(3);
        await TimeTaker(4);
        await TimeTaker(5);
    }

    private async Task<int> TimeTaker(int setting)
    {
        switch (setting)
        {
            case 1:
                LabelInfo.Text = "case 1";
                break;
            case 2:
                LabelInfo.Text = "case 2";
                break;
            case 3:
                LabelInfo.Text = "case 3";
                LabelInfo.CssClass = "text-info";
                break;
            case 4:
                LabelInfo.Text = "case 4";
                LabelInfo.CssClass = "text-warning";
                break;
            case 5:
                LabelInfo.Text = "case 5";
                LabelInfo.CssClass = "text-warning";
                break;
        }
        //Delay the return so we have time to see the updated label on the web page.
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        return 1;
    }
```

This is purely a quick example but I would expect when the button is pressed as it calls each method it would update the label and this can be seen on the screen as its within the update panel. it does hit breakpoints as expected but the label does not update until the final method resulting in "case 5" set on the label with the new css class.

Comment: Is this an ASP.NET Web Forms application?

Comment: Hello, Yes this is a .NET Web Application - I did show a code snipped for the ASPX page too but it removed when preview/posting.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote - I tried to post a question in a way SO asks you to. I'll go learn how to utilise SignalR and get live updates back from the server instead of trying to make an update panel post live updates before the method has been fully completed.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/performance-and-caching/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-45), the only way to execute asynchronous code is using page asynchronous tasks.

Nevertheless, `btnTakeTime_Click` will return after the first blocking await (`await Task.Delay(1000);`). The state of `LabelInfo` will depend on how long that asynchronous code takes to run and how long the execution of the page (which is unaware that that code is running) takes to run.

Additionally, nothing of that changes the HTTP (1.0/1.1) protocol or how Web Forms work which is a request being set by the user agent to the server and the server sending a request back. No matter how many times the state of `LabelInfo` changes during the request handling, it will only have a final state.